# Any workaround to efficiently calculate distance between list of coordinates in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, geopandas

I have data comes with zip/post code, longitude, latitude info. I want to calculate zip distance between one zip code against the rest then do same recursively without duplicated distance values in python. However, I am able to use `geosphere` R library for distance calculation. However, my objective is to get zip code distances by coordinate in python. I found `GeoPandas`, or `Geod` might provide built-in function to calculate zip coordinate distances but still not getting same out that I got from R implementation. Does anyone knows how to find coordinate distances in python? Can anyone suggest possible workaround to do this? Any thoughts?

**minimal data**

here is the minimal data that I used in R for distance calculation.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(post_code = c(201L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 
317L, 318L, 319L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 
396L, 397L, 398L), latitude = c(30.82, 32.08, 32.39, 32.31, 32.38, 
32.31, 32.29, 32.14, 32.2, 32.13, 32.29, 32.38, 32.16, 32.16, 
32.18, 32.19, 32.19, 32.36, 32.27, 32.07), longtitude = c(-83.03, 
-82.62, -82.52, -82.52, -82.52, -82.1, -82.33, -82.92, -82.34, 
-82.2, -82.94, -82.82, -82.61, -82.39, -82.58, -82.86, -82.56, 
-82.89, -82.69, -82.5)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

**current R attempt**

here is my current R implementation to calculate distance between different postal code; essentially I want to calculate zip or post code distance between one to another recursively.

```
library(geosphere)
df_src=df
df_trg=df

colnames(df_src)=c("src_post_code", "src_lat", "src_long")
colnames(df_trg)=c("trg_post_code", "trg_lat", "trg_long")

get_distance <- function(post_code, radius=1e-5){
    tmp=df_src[df_src$src_post_code==post_code,]
    dist=distHaversine(tmp[,1:2,with=FALSE],df_trg[,1:2,with=FALSE])
    res= as.data.frame(
        post_code=df_src$src_post_code,
        lat=df_src$src_lat
        long=df_src$src_long
        dist= dist*1e-5
    )
    return(res)
}

final_output= as.data.frame(lapply(df_src$src_post_code, get_distance))
```

but doing this way is not very efficient, because actual list of post code are 40k+ and doing this calculation gave me computational burden even using parallel processing.

However, my objective is doing this in python by ingesting above R logic. I think Geod or GeoPandas might help me with that, still getting same output in python. Can anyone point me out how to find zip/post code coordinate distance between one to another recursively? Any thoughts?

recursively I mean is like this graph below:

[image]

so tabular view on the left shows how original input data looks like; the graph on the right shows how I want to find coordinate distance one to rest recursively in python.

**current python attempt**:

```
from pyproj import Geod
import pandas as pd

gist='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/8f89821df2c09e3196849095d6203e07/raw/6348a43252966be69d4e2c826aaa1c39e113c899/zip_code_data.csv'
df= pd.read_csv(gist, index_col=0)

df_coord = df[['src_lat', 'src_long', 'trg_lat', 'trg_long']].to_numpy().T
df['dist'] = wsg84.inv(*df_coord )[-1] / 1000
```

but output is not same as the one from R code. Can anyone suggest better way of doing this? Any better idea or approach to do this efficiently in python?

**update**

I tried @Benoit Fgt' solution below on actual data which has 40k+ zip code and lan/long info, and it gave me memory error instead. Is there way to do parallel processing in python? Any idea?

Comment: You have more than 8*10**8 combinations!!! Are you sure you need all results? Does it make sense? Maybe get nearest postcodes around a code could be sufficient, no?

Comment: @Corralien yeah, I aware that and yes I need whole calculation. In this case, can we split 40k+ rows data into multiple batches and run it on multiple processers in parallel? Plus, do you have possible thoughts on this that light me up? Thanks

Comment: Even if you split your work into multiple batches and run it on multiple processors in parallel, do you have enough memory to store all results?

Comment: @Corralien yes I have enough memory. I tried your approach but distance output is not right, I think we shouldn't use `np.radian` for coordinates. Could you elaborate your approach with complete picture? Any update?

Comment: It looks like in R you use the haversine, that is a cheaper calculation than the more correct from pyproj.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the expected output from the sample. How about something like this (the code can be improved I guess):

```
from pyproj import Geod
import pandas as pd
import itertools

geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")
gist='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/8f89821df2c09e3196849095d6203e07/raw/6348a43252966be69d4e2c826aaa1c39e113c899/zip_code_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(gist)

coords = list(zip(df.latitude, df.longtitude, df.post_code))
combs = list(itertools.combinations(coords, 2))
lons1, lats1, lons2, lats2, zip_code_from, zip_code_to = [], [], [], [], [], []
zip_code_from, zip_code_to
for pair in combs: 
    lons1.append(pair[0][0])
    lats1.append(pair[0][1])
    lons2.append(pair[1][0])
    lats2.append(pair[1][1])
    zip_code_from.append(pair[0][2])
    zip_code_to.append(pair[1][2])
    
az12, az21, dist = geod.inv(lons1, lats1, lons2, lats2)
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(zip_code_from, zip_code_to, dist)), columns=['pos_code_from', 'pos_code_to', 'dist']).sort_values('dist')
```

This results to:

```
    pos_code_from   pos_code_to dist
38  312 314 145.395037
54  313 314 1017.765195
37  312 313 1163.160201
29  311 373 1601.912638
100 317 319 1744.891723
... ... ... ...
96  315 396 88226.021581
86  315 318 91606.658285
89  315 371 93807.304276
8   201 370 94573.135189
4   201 315 106058.180885
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. if we have 10k zip code to calculate zip distances, how can we do it by using your current attempt? plus, can we change the output format with columns of `zip_code_from`, `zip_code_to`, `lat`, `long`, `distance_value` in final output? thanks

Comment: For 10k zip codes, you would obtain 50M combinations. Is your issue time or memory? I have updated my answer so that you have zip_code_from, zip_code_to as 2 different columns. Not sure what you want to have in the columns lat long but I think you can easily modify the snippet to add what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, just to test

Try with sklearn:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, DistanceMetric

# gist='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/...'
df = pd.read_csv(gist, index_col=0)
coords = np.radians(df[['latitude', 'longtitude']])

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
tree = BallTree(coords, metric=dist)

distances, indices = tree.query(coords, k=len(df))
```

Do you have memory error with this code?